# Can the Structure of a React App be hidden behind a login?

Tags: reactjs, security, authentication

Our React App is secured by a login. This prevents attackers from accessing user-specific content because they are unable to begin a session without credentials.

We are now ready to start testing with real world users. For this we would like to host our app on a publicly accessible endpoint. But we cannot allow unauthorized individuals to explore our app. Of course they would not get to see user data but they could potentially view our apps structure and features and steal our product, correct?

Is there a way to prevent this or should we instead only allow access from a VPN for the initial test phase?

Comment: *they could potentially view our apps structure and features and steal our product* You could say the same about pretty much any website. If I were you, I'd obfuscate and minify, then host it anywhere, don't worry too much about snoopers, I doubt anyone'd care enough

Comment: @CertainPerformance Obfuscate and minify, got it. Would hosting it on an obscure domain/subdomain (random characters) be a good idea?

Comment: You could, but I wouldn't bother.

Comment: I would argue that obfuscation really isn't that useful; but yes, it's not really much of a concern. If anyone *were* to steal your app, you would have a solid legal case. No one is going around stealing facebook's client, so you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

React is a bundled application. That means your entire react app is in a single javascript file. Even if you had a login on the react app, someone could still just... bypass it.

A way to prevent this would probably be just a simple nodejs server which has a login:

```js
app.get('/secretapp/:password', (Req,Res) => {
    if (Req.params.password == "hunter2") {
        Res.send("react_app.js")
    } else {
        Res.status(404).end() // What route? Nothing to see here. Go away.
    }
})
```

Otherwise, a VPN is not a bad choice.

Comment: What if I create a separate react app for the login and send back the actual app as a response to a successful login? That would basically follow the same principal, right?

Comment: I mean, sure, but in my opinion you'd be doing more work than you'd need to be doing.